# Arduino Clone CH340G 'Error Compiling for Board Arduino/Genuino Uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I brought a cheap Arduino board from AilExpress  and after searching around the forum rooms ,installed the drivers for CH340G board. For some reason I am still unable to compile and run the code on the board. 
The IDE keeps stating 'Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

Any help would be most welcome.

I have checked my COM port its COM6 and does state (CH430G) next to it.

Kind regards.

Comment: An error during compilation has nothing to do with a cheap Arduino clone since the upload starts after compilation.

Comment: When you encounter an error in the Arduino IDE you'll see a button on the right side of the orange bar "Copy error messages". Click that button, then edit your question to include the error messages, using [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to put them in a code block.

Comment: this is the error message I am getting : Arduino: 1.8.3 (Windows Store 1.8.6.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

readlink G:\OneDrive\Programming\Ardniuo_HomeProjects\ardunino-wifiboard_t\T1-wifi\T1-wifi.ino: The system cannot find the file specified.

Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it happened but the answer was in the error message which was " Show verbose output during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences."

so I went into File --> Preferences and selected the following

- "Show verbose output during [x] compilation [x] upload" both are tick
- "Check for updates on startup"  tick
- Enable code folding tick

I then moved my sketch file from Onedrive to G:\Documents\Arduino\Wifi-Test

compile and upload , "bob's your uncle"  it works

ensure you have selected in your board manager "Arduino /  Genuino Uno"